# Is it conceivable that strictly according to the provisions of the C11 (or above) standard that this program could be optimized to print hello?

Tags: c, c11, strict-aliasing

Given this program, strict aliasing rules and type based alias analysis optimization:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stddef.h>
#include<stdalign.h>
#include<assert.h>

struct thing {
  int x;
  int y;
};

static_assert(sizeof("hello") < sizeof(struct thing),"buffer can't hold text");

int main() {

    alignas(struct thing) char buffer[sizeof(struct thing)] = "hello";
    void *ptr = buffer;
    struct thing* s = ptr;
    
    s->x = 20;
    s->y = 30;

    printf("%s",buffer);

    return 0;
}
```

could a conforming compiler decide that the buffer never changes, so it can be placed in read-only segment (or similar) and thus this will print hello? (works as expected in practise)

Perhaps I shall add a motivating example as to why one would want to do this. Say one have created an arena allocator that works fine when passed an initial slab of memory by malloc. No problem, any time we write to memory gotten from this allocator we are changing effective types on first write to the (void*) we get. However if our arena allocator is initialized with a char* gotten from stack memory (say aligned suitably for any type we will write to it), it is a big no no as we would be aliasing the char buffer.

This leads me to feel this is a hole in the language. Why can we not stack allocate suitably aligned untyped (but sized) memory?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but it looks like the program has UB and can therefore print whatever it wants.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem.: The Standard is not intended to fully describe everything necessary to make an implementation suitable for any particular tasks.  Instead, it expects that implementations intended for various purposes will extend the semantics of the language by specifying behavior in more cases than mandated. 
 Implementations suitable for low-level programming extend the language in such fashion, and implementations that support absolutely nothing beyond what the Standard requires are unsuitable for low-level programming.

Comment: @supercat Are you explaining me what "undefined behaviour" means? I know.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem.: Under a pedantic reading of the rules, most non-contrived programs violate the constraints of N1570 6.5p7.  The question of which programs to process meaningfully is left as a Quality of Implementation issue.  All non-contrived compilers extend the language to usefully support constructs like `struct foo someStruct = {1,someFunction()};` at automatic duration, or `someStruct.intArray[n] = 23;` even though both access an object of type `struct foo` during its lifetime, but not through an lvalue of compatible type.  On the flip side, neither clang nor gcc...

Comment: ...upholds all the corner cases provided for in the Standard except when invoked with `-fno-strict-aliasing`.  If one interprets the footnote as implying that quality implementations should only interpret the rule as saying when compilers must assume that things may alias *even when there's no other particular evidence that they would do so*, this construct should have no problem, but then again neither should most of the constructs the maintainers of clang and gcc refuse to handle./

Comment: @supercat I have no idea what any of this means. The question is simple. Does the standard prescribe meaning to this program? The answer is no. Full stop, case closed. There may or may not be other factors that give meaning to this program, but the C standard is not one of them.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem.: The Standard *describes* behavior for many more programs than it *prescribes*.  Indeed, it doesn't prescribe behavior for *any* non-trivial programs for freestanding implementations.  If parts of the Standard and platform documentation together describe the behavior of some action, but some other part of the Standard classifies it as UB, the Standard doesn't require that implementations give priority to the former in all cases, or even in any.  Instead, it relies upon quality implementations to give priority to the former absent a good reason to do otherwise.

Comment: @supercat The C Standard places requirements on (IOW, prescribes) behaviour of certain programs. I am reading it right now and that is what I am seeing. Requirements. That's what all standards generally do. They place requirements on things. There may or may not be descriptions in the Standard that are not requirements, but I am not interested in them and am not talking about them. The Standard does not require anything at all from programs that exhibit UB, it says so itself, so of course it does not require implementations to prioritise anything, it is just a special case of no requirements.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem.: The C Standard defines two categories of programs: Strictly Conforming C Programs and Conforming C Programs.  The former imposes requirements that cannot be satisfied by non-trivial programs for freestanding implementations.  The latter imposes just about no requirements.  Compiler writers view the Standard as imposing requirements upon programs, but the way its categories of conformance are defined prevents it from exercising any normative authority over most practical C programs.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem.: A conforming but poor quality implementation could behave in arbitrary fashion if given the indicated code, but could also do so given almost *any* C program, including Strictly Conforming ones.  The ability to process *any* useful C programs is a Quality of Implementation issue, rather than a conformance one.  The authors of the Standard acknowledge this in the Rationale document at http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf (see page 24, starting at line 20).  The Standard can be usefully read as describing a "core" language...

Comment: ...which implementations should extend so as to best serve their intended purposes.  It makes no attempt to describe everything an implementation must do to be suitable for any particular purpose.

Comment: @supercat The question I have asked is very simple. Syntactically it admits two answers, yes and no. One of them must be right, the other is wrong. It looks like you insist that the question is semantically meaningless. I am not interested in discussing that.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem.: Have you read the published Rationale for the C Standard?  It clarifies what the Standard was written to mean.

Answer (score 4):

Alignment isn't the only issue here. The effective type of `buffer` is a character array but you make lvalue access as `int`. That's a pretty clear strict aliasing violation and undefined behavior. Anything can happen.

"Anything" includes the `s->x = 20;` write happening, or getting optimized away, or the program crashing because the string was allocated in read-only section, or the program not crashing but the string remaining intact because it was allocated in true NVM like flash memory.

Comment: As for a "conforming compiler", the only requirement is that it must accept a strictly conforming program. And this isn't one, since it contains undefined behavior.

Comment: Isn't it allowed to write any type into a `char` buffer? Would [_this_](https://godbolt.org/z/h6f89nY3b) make a difference?

Comment: @TedLyngmo No, it is the other way around. You are allowed to inspect any type byte by byte through a character pointer. And the aliasing rules has an exception from lvalue access when done through a character type. Your example is a different exception, it is "an aggregate or union type" which also contains an exception in the list (C17 6.5).

Comment: This is the answer I expected. Seems like a big problem that one can essentially not use "stack allocated storage" (sans union trickery) because it has a declared type which can interfere through strict aliasing rules. I wish this could be amended through stack allocation without a declared type. I.e. alignas(required) untyped buffer[size]. That would behave as it were the result of malloc but with the set alignment requirement. The reasonable use case for it is for example say you have an arena allocatr that works fine with storage from malloc, why shld it not work with properly aligned stack

Comment: @anonymouscoward Non-standard functions like alloca might work like that. Essentially they just increase the stack pointer by a number of bytes. But the best bet is to use `-fno-strict-aliasing` or just stay away from gcc. Most strict aliasing abuse problems in gcc have been fixed long before C11 release, but people occasionally manage to create scenarios where it breaks still. The whole thing boils down to defects in the language standard.

Comment: @Lundin other than "this is the rules following from strict aliasing" is there anything that really would prohibit amending the situation like the inclusion of alloca as part of the standard? At least an optional one. It annoys me to no end that if one wants to use stack memory to pass to e.g. an arena allocator then one must change the implementation of the allocator entirely to use union hacks or a whole bunch of memcpy's.

Comment: @anonymouscoward No easy fix. Though you can sometimes write your routines to use character type arithmetic with `unsigned char*`. Also in practice you could pre-allocate some chunk of memory reserved for your program, where the compiler has no idea what's allocated. Such chunks then get "no effective type" as if returned by malloc. This is for example how one has to regard memory-mapped registers in a microcontroller, that the compiler knows nothing about.

Comment: @Lundin admittedly there is of course good reason to be careful with alloca and blowing the stack. The usecase you mention seems safe. The one case I can think of then is to have an `extern void* buffer;` that is set up in a linker script(placed to a suitable alignment, and ensuring a big enough mapped size). One must then take care to ensure alignment  any time memory is handed out from this. Of course, would be nice to not have to go to the hassle of doing that, but at the same time not having to depend on malloc being present.

Comment: @anonymouscoward: The `alloca` function can only be efficiently processed on implementations that can efficiently use a frame pointer.  In 16-bit x86, which had frame-relative addressing but not stack-relative, support for `alloca` was almost "free".  On platforms which are designed for stack-relative addressing, use of stack-based `alloca` or VLAs will increase the amount of code required to load and store "ordinary" automatic-duration objects.

Answer (score 0):

The Standard invites implementations whose customers would find constructs like yours useful to specify that they will process such code "in a documented manner characteristic of the environment" even in cases where the Standard itself imposes no requirements.  Because the authors had no reason to expect that implementations whose customers would find such support useful would balk at providing it, they saw no need to mandate it.  Instead, such support is left as a Quality of Implementation issue.  Implementations designed and configured to be suitable for low-level programming will provide it, but those that are not designed and configured that way might not.

As for what might happen if an implementation doesn't provide such support, some compilers that are designed and configured to be suitable only for programs that will exclusively process trusted inputs (e.g. clang and gcc with full optimizations enabled) will deliberately regard as impossible any input which the Standard would not forbid them from processing in nonsensical fashion, and omit code which would only be relevant if such input is received.  Consequently, such implementations may process actions the Standard characterizes as Undefined Behavior in nonsensical ways which are not constrained by normal laws of time or causality.